# Searching log file for specific matching error code

Tags: linux

How to search a unix log file for a specific error code and display only the variable that matches that search?I have tried using grep and egrep commands.

Comment: What are you searching for and why is grep not working?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you have tried this

grep **TextYouWantToExclude** **YourLogfile.abc** | grep -v ERROR

Answer (score 0):

And did grep or egrep not work for you?

I use vim for this. The command `:g/<search>` comes in very handy because it filters out all lines that do not match `<search>`. `<search>` can be a regular expression just as one would use with grep.

Answer (score 0):

grep -i error_code log_file

This will display all the instances of error code found in log file.